# java object resize on window resize

Tags: java, swing, resize, window

I've to resize few elements like JTable on window resize. I've been trying this code, but it doesn't work correctly:

```
    table.setLocation(0, 23);
    Dimension siz = contentPane.getMaximumSize();
    table.setSize(siz.height, siz.width - 46);
```

It resizing my table, but it making it endless, what i don't want. Also I would like to connent scrollbar to this table, and if it's possible - set column width in precentage

Comment: Use layout managers to accomplish this for free.  Besides, a `JTable` should be in a `JScrollPane`, so you should be changing it's size...By default, `getMaximumSize` returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`...

Comment: *"Also I would like to connent scrollbar to this table"* - Layout managers and `JScrollPane` should do this automatically.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: ok, but what i mean by "on window resize" is when you click Minimize/Maximize button(second button on right top of the window) and sorry for my english

Comment: So?  Resize by dragging, resize be change of extended state.  Layout managers will do this, that's what they are designed for

Comment: ok, maybe this will show you my problem - this is minimized window - http://s21.postimg.org/nxkrma1iv/app.jpg and this is maximized - http://s17.postimg.org/ttk19zhkf/app.jpg

Comment: Still looks like you're not using layout managers, nor are you encapsulating the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem (with resizing) has more to do with your reliance on form editors then anything to do with Swing or Java

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

You're also don't seem to be utilising a `JScrollPane` to house the `JTable` in.  Have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

[image: Sizing]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ResizeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ResizeTest();
    }

    public ResizeTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;
        private JButton historyButton;
        private JButton otherButton;

        public TestPane() {

            table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(10, 10));
            historyButton = new JButton("History");
            otherButton = new JButton("Other");

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            buttons.add(historyButton);
            buttons.add(otherButton);
            add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JPanel footers = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            JLabel left = new JLabel("Left");
            left.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
            JLabel right = new JLabel("Right");
            right.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
            footers.add(left);
            footers.add(right);

            add(footers, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant

Comment: Or maybe not, now i can't edit window in Design tab, i'm using eclipse and this is how it looks like: http://s1.postimg.org/705yd5li7/app.jpg

Comment: Form Editor = Bad idea, and Eclipse's frankly is among the worst.  Take the time to learn to code you UI's it will give you a greater appreciation for how to solve common problems, use multiple containers to generate complex layouts and a appreciation for when a form editor should be used and when it shouldn't.  Seriously, I've 15 years without one for the majority of my work